# Is a fresh install of linux equivalent to a honeypot?

Tags: security

Hello I was wondering whether a a fresh install of Debian connected to the internet without further protection (iptable or whatever) is safe or equivalent to a [honeypot](https://www.honeynet.org/papers/bots). Do we have some people that demonstrated that a fresh linux install running naked on the internet for hours or days won't get compromised by itself for future use ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really a honey pot.  But you could treat it like one.

But if you wanted to do that experiment, there might be a way to use `tripwire` to look for changes an intruder may have made to 'own' the system.

Set it up,  leave it open and idle.  Then go back after your period is up and look for evidence.  (Take steps to make sure `tripwire` itself wasn't crippled.  Back up its initial database off the host.  use fresh copies of its executables to audit)

If you were having security updates installed automatically, you'd have to exclude the changes that process made.

But then there are the intruders that just visit without making changes.  You can look for logins in your log files.  You can probably even set up `iptables` to log connections to and from the test machine and check that for odd activity

Comment: Awesome stuff, would you say it's reasonable to keep using a linux install that have been on the internet for days without an iptable or would you recommend to reinstall my debian once I learn how to operate an iptable and make it the first installed thing ?

Comment: A lot would depend on the environment.  If, for example, you were like me, and had the linux installed on a home system, with an IPv4 ISP, fronted by a wifi router that did NAT, then that is already a pretty good fire wall.  It's actually kind of a pain to configure to let stuff from outside connect even when you want to.   On the other hand, if you share a wifi with people who are constantly being infected by malware, perhaps you are in a hostile environment.   One thing going for you is that personal linux systems are not big targets for criminal malware.  Website hosts different story.

Comment: Once upon a time, spammers were fond of personal linux systems with email servers to forward spam though.   I believe its not common these days, with people mostly using blackhole lists to refuse mail from addresses listed as ISP dynamics

Comment: oh okay I see, i'm going through a router but I don't know whether it filters anything, I usually don't have to open up ports on the routers to use various softwares so I don't know. Appart from that I don't think i'm in a hostile environnement. Once I learn iptable i'll still make fresh reinstall tho since I'm still searching for a good config i'm doing lot of stuff i don't control. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Certainly a fresh install of anything is not "equivalent" to a honeypot. Honeypots are systems that are purposefully installed to track or slow down intruders, but there's no reason a newly installed system won't become part of such a project.

If you want to know whether a newly installed system is vulnerable to a remote exploit soon after it is installed, then I guess that depends on whether any remotely exploitable vulnerabilities in software that is running on the newly installed system have been discovered since the version of the software that was installed. So without knowing WHAT you installed and WHEN, and without an ability to predict the future, we really can't say...

Comment: i told you i installed Debian and let it run on the internet for few days so why do you ask what and when ?

Comment: Because the Debian security team produces updates all the time so what you installed yesterday might not be what you install today, and of course the schedule on which new vulnerabilities are discovered is unpredictable!

Comment: I'm not a security expert I just wanted to know if it was reasonable to start using a linux install without iptable or other security measure or if it is better to reinstall my Debian after I learned how to use iptable and install it before anything.

Comment: "if it was reasonable to start using a linux install without iptable" — well, sure... if you don't need iptables there's nothing that obligates you to use it. reinstalling Debian in order to use iptables sounds nonsensical to me. I think I must be missing your point.

Comment: What I meant is that i've been running debian naked for days on the internet so my fear is that malwares already infested my system (maybe it's unreasonable fear that's my question), since i intend to keep using debian maybe it would be wise to reinstall debian and install iptable before going on the internet so the system stays clean, i don't know

Comment: @ChiseledAbs but what are you planning to filter out with `iptables`? Something you're aware of that's got a security bug in it? If you know about such a bug, chances are the Debian security team does too. More importantly, since it's a fresh install, there shouldn't be many servers running that you aren't aware of anyway —or if they are running, it's probably because you installed them on purpose, in which case I doubt you would filter them out!

Comment: Well idk I thought that there was some general guidelines on how to use iptable, for instance that you close all ports except few ones that you need. I'm looking for some material where to learn how to make your system more secure with iptable or other tools that

Answer (score 3):

[OpenBSD](http://www.openbsd.org/) prides itself on security, and has the [slogan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenBSD#Slogan) “Only two remote holes in the default install, in a heck of a long time!”. The long time is 19 years and counting, so that's about one remote hole per 10 years.

OpenBSD focuses on security, and has a rather minimalist default installation, so one can expect that Debian's record isn't as good. (However, OpenBSD does activate the SSH server by default, which many distributions don't do.) I'm not aware of any study that's been done on Debian or other Linux distributions. Still, going by a definition of “fresh install of Linux running naked” where the user isn't doing anything beyond what's necessary to download available security updates, there can't have been many periods of time where a machine was vulnerable.

Of course if you wanted to connect a machine to the Internet and use it normally without doing security upgrades, that's another matter. Web browsers are complex beasts that many people try to attack; if you don't apply security updates to your browser, that's your #1 point of vulnerability by far.

Comment: Problem is that the only reason why OpenBSD is so secure is because the low amount of users it has. linux isn't more secure than windows (unless you're implying that paid professional microsoft developpers  are worst programmers than  the unpaid workers from linux) it's just that it has less users so less people are trying to break in.

Comment: @ChiseledAbs No, that's not true at all. OpenBSD *does* put more effort into security (at the expense of functionality). Windows's security used to be catastrophic; starting around Windows XP they started putting some effort into it but they have a huge legacy to cope with. The fact that a programmer is paid for a project has no correlation with their competence.